# i keep crashing and getting this when I try o play minecraft, I am on 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I do have mods but I removed them and it still did not work

```
Completely ignored arguments: [--nativeLauncherVersion, 301]
[17:21:20] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: PixieYAM
[17:21:20] [Client thread/INFO]: (Session ID is <censored>)
[17:21:22] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[17:21:23] [Client thread/INFO]: Reloading ResourceManager: Default
[17:21:24] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Starting up SoundSystem...
[17:21:24] [Thread-5/INFO]: Initializing LWJGL OpenAL
[17:21:24] [Thread-5/INFO]: (The LWJGL binding of OpenAL.  For more information, see http://www.lwjgl.org)
[17:21:25] [Thread-5/INFO]: OpenAL initialized.
[17:21:25] [Sound Library Loader/INFO]: Sound engine started
[17:21:25] [Client thread/INFO]: Created: 1024x512 textures-atlas
[17:23:11] [Client thread/INFO]: Connecting to MC.HYPIXEL.NET, 25565
[17:23:13] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[17:23:13] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] Attempting to send you the resource pack...
[17:23:13] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT]                          
[17:23:13] [Client thread/WARN]: Received unknown passenger for bmu['86twrpp3iz'/282, l='MpServer', x=-96.50, y=30.00, z=48.50]
[17:23:13] [Client thread/WARN]: Received unknown passenger for bmu['111j2774s3'/286, l='MpServer', x=-96.50, y=30.00, z=-5.50]
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffe9866628c, pid=1048, tid=17736
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_25-b18) (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ig75icd64.dll+0x55628c]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\sedon_000\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\hs_err_pid1048.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Comment: Please add more information about your PC setup, while a crash dump can be useful, knowibg the whole story can help a lot more. Try adding things like OS version, RAM, and especially if you have any mods